# UserEventAgent Not Responding (MacBook Pro 2018 Mojave)

Tags: activity-monitor

I opened activityMonitor and covered that UserEventAgent lighted red color.
How can I fix this?

Comment: click on the Activity monitor window that will bring it to the front.

Comment: Well, you can 'fix' it by force-quitting it or rebooting - but that won't tell you why it happened or which plugin/user process had hung.